# How to configure Super CSV to quote all values except column names?

Tags: java, csv, supercsv

Requirements are:

- Every value in records should be quoted.
- Column names should separated by comma and space(, ).

For example

```
Name, Age, Location
"A","154","California"
"B","2","New York"
```

How do I create such SuperCSV Preference for writing?

Comment: "But do not quote column names" and "Column names should separated by comma and space(, )" seems to be incompatible

Comment: Do not quote column names means ```[X] "Name","Age","Location" ```, Column Names should be separated by comma and space means [✓] `Name, Age, Location`. Are they incompatible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following Custom Quote Mode:

```
public class AllExceptHeaderQuoteMode implements QuoteMode {

    @Override
    public boolean quotesRequired(String csvColumn, CsvContext context, CsvPreference preference) {
        if (1 == context.getLineNumber()) {
            /*
             * Case whene column names are written
             */
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Using Custom Quote Mode:

```
CsvPreference preference = new CsvPreference.Builder(CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE).useQuoteMode(new AllExceptHeaderQuoteMode()).build());
```